# Cannot change Redis data dir even after changing the user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redis, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I am running redis 3.0.6 in ubuntu 16.04 server. I have edited the `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file & changed the dir option from `/var/lib/redis to /home/redisdata` & changed the owner of /home/redisdata to redis.

I have moved the dump.rdb from /var/lib/redis to /home/redisdata
& tried to start the redis-server. But it keeps on saying :

```
Can't chdir to '/home/redisdata': Permission denied
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Post such questions on http://serverfault.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/help

Comment: Which command did you use to change the owner of /home/redisdata? try this command: sudo chown redis. /home/redisdata

Comment: Yes i have used chown to change the owner . But i think it's some issues with the redis-server itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in case you are still having this issue, try this: edit the file

```
/etc/systemd/system/redis.service
```

commenting the line

```
#ProtectHome=yes
```

It will complain about the file change and ask you to do a

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

That should do it

```
sudo service redis-server restart
```